# Zend Framework2 ShoppingCart Suggestions?

Tags: arrays, loops, zend-framework2, shopping-cart, protected

Im Using ZendFramework2.5 and as part of my exercise i want to implement a [ShoppingCart](https://github.com/martyshka/ShoppingCart).

My CartController looks like this:

```
public function indexAction(){
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'cart' => $this->ShoppingCart()->cart(),
        'total_items' => $this->ShoppingCart()->total_items(),
        'total_sum' => $this->ShoppingCart()->total_sum(),
    ));
}
```

print_r($cart) on my View gives me an Array like this:

```
Array ( 
[7a084caa72cc1bdef3ad749a517e8aa71620a54b] => ShoppingCart\Entity\ShoppingCartEntity 
    Object ( 
    [id:protected] => XYZ [product:protected] => Book: ZF2 for beginners [qty:protected] => 1 [price:protected] => 15.15 [product_properties:protected]
    )
)
```

Now I am not sure how to go on, because

1. i dont know how to iterate through this array properly.
2. maybe there is a better approach than iterating through this array on the   View.

Thanks for any suggestions anyone may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value of `$cart` array is a `ShoppingCart\Entity\ShoppingCartEntity` and implements `ShoppingCart\Entity\ShoppingCartEntityInterface`.
This interface provides all public methods you need :

```
interface ShoppingCartEntityInterface
{
public function getId();
public function getProduct();
public function getQty();
public function getPrice();
public function setId($id);
public function setProduct($product);
public function setQty($qty);
public function setPrice($price);
public function setProductProperties(array $properties);
public function getProductProperties();
}
```

Comment: Now i can use  foreach ($cart as $itm) { echo $itm->getProduct(); }